# Rails Server working in command line. Not at Localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, localhost

```
rails server
```

=> Booting Puma

=> Rails 5.2.0 application starting in development

=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options

```
[44266] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[44266] * Version 3.6.2 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
[44266] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
[44266] * Environment: development
[44266] * Process workers: 1
[44266] * Preloading application
[44266] * Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
[44266] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[44266] - Worker 0 (pid: 44286) booted, phase: 0
^C[44266] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
[44266] === puma shutdown: 2018-06-12 14:28:53 -0500 ===
[44266] - Goodbye!
Exiting
```

went to `http://www.localhost3000.org/`

says you forgot to start your server

```
Running
Rails 5.2.0
Postgesql 9.6
```

Comment: just use `localhost:3000`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `http://www.localhost3000.org/` is a website that someone bought to help you when you mistype your attempt to get to your localhost. It's not your own server responding

As the website suggests, try to go instead to `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Postgresql is on.

Comment: How do I get the app to run on the localhost. localhost is working. did I miss a step?

Comment: Is your server running? If not, that's the first step. If it is, navigating to localhost:3000 should take you to your root_path on the app. Navigate to localhost:3000 and see if there is any activity on your server log. Your server log is often the best place to see what's going on with your app.

Comment: yes the server is running. localhost:3000 says 'yay! you're on rails'

Comment: Most likely you don't have a root_path route that goes to a controller that is serving a view. So your server is working well, now you just need to add to your app.

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'


  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html 

 resources :feedbacks, only: [:post]

Answer (score 0):

Use this address `localhost:3000`. The link you included is a live website someone has published as a reminder to start your server.

Answer (score 0):

Use this address `http://localhost:3000` but you can still edit your url, follow this article: [Edit localhost](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/)